# Is it possible to have optionally nested key-value pairs in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to have an object like this:

```
const foo = { ... }; // how?

console.log(foo.a); // '1'
console.log(foo.a.bar); // { 'prop1': 1, 'prop2': 2 }
console.log(foo.b); // '2'
console.log(foo.b.bar); // { 'prop1': 1, 'prop2': 2 }
```

So, the default value of `foo.a` is described in the comment after the statement with the value `'1'`. But I would also like to go deeper into the object, to access a deeper property `bar`, of which `a` is the parent.

Something to demonstrate the desired structure:

```
const foo = {
  a: '1',
  [a.bar]: { prop1: 1, prop2: 2 },
  b: '2',
  [b.bar]: { prop1: 1, prop2: 2 }
}
```

Is this possible with TypeScript **without using a function to call it**? So something like this would not be a good solution for this case:

```
foo.a();
foo.a().bar();
```

Comment: This might not be what you're saying, but it looks to me like you want `foo.a` to be of type number and yet still have a `bar` property that is an object. I'm not sure how you'd do that in JavaScript in the first place. Even if it's a string, you're not going to get there. You might be able to get analogous behavior by overriding `toString` but I'm not going to get too speculative until you get a chance to weigh in.

Comment: Or, reading it one more time, maybe the answer to your question is "no," unfortunately.

Comment: To add to @DavidP.Caldwell 's comment, even though it's (semi-)possible, writing sth like this would be a grave anti-pattern. Don't do it, please.

Comment: Yes, I see there's an answer going the route I suggested (overriding `toString`) but I'm with @Przemyslaw -- don't do it. There must be a better way. You might end up with deeper nesting (having properties like "value" and "children" at each level or something) but it'll be much easier to work with.

Comment: Thank you for your insights @DavidP.Caldwell and `@Przemyslaw`, I've decided to not use this because of the arguments provided by you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't use this pattern.**

Another version of what you seem to be asking is "Can I extend primitive types with additional properties"?

> Is this possible?

Yes (sort of), but it's a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) and I've never seen a compelling case for it. Here are two reasons why you shouldn't do it:

1. Anyone reviewing the code (even your future self) won't be expecting extra properties on these types, which will make it harder to read and understand.
2. Especially if the property names are going to be dynamic, there's a higher likelihood of overwriting/[shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) existing, standard property names on the object form of the primitive, which will almost certainly cause bugs.

With that out of the way — and, again, don't use this (you've been warned) — here's how you can do it:

> References:
>
> - [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)
> - [String primitives and String objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#string_primitives_and_string_objects)

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBARgQwE4wLwwN4wA5JNgRgC4YCAaHPbAJhOpgF8BuAKBdElgDMQQ1MWMGAhIB5OACsApsCgA6BBAgBLAOZgAFAHJwUrRSyIUDAJRlB8MZJnzFK9dqgB3EPszxkjMy2ZsA9ABUMAAqABZSMFAAntgRIFwwAEQ8IIkwyhBELBgWIkm6aQBkAkJCRiQ5paW4+MQwYACuALZwUkisVUI1NCSNLW0dpb5Cw5ZJzqkwxZWl5SWd3XV9re0WVd209c0rgyODvgwsAX5sHBAgADZScsBXyBomrCx+fiGhGekQwjAABgDKUCQyjAqh+MA0IGssjM9RAsAQv2gQJBYI0uGUTWUUGUADcpCYsmdLtcLiBVBoUgpHjAXjAAcjVPkwFI0oZkBVKLUSOROT0YPQGIx-K8AJogBowYAIMAwJHA1TKLhRdKwBoqEHCMDK+KRcIQCJNKRQUIgAAmmXY4HOVzkpPJ9PlFN4VOptMSBUtkGJtrJTpACjkUBADpBD1dr3dzMSnutJN9PwAJBhKQgGD9w0yWacrd67X6A0GAKrYWJIADCiikYaYNIjogAcgBRaMx3O+lNyIwZrCLbkUDZ0IWtm15ylwDMhxmJCasjxIDm90j9qibAVCokj32T-PjjPTlzRjdx8ljwMgYuliv66u1pLBADqokPOc3J+dcE7yG7vLqPIH-KFIA)

```ts
const bar = { prop1: 1, prop2: 2 };

const foo = {
  a: Object.assign('one', { bar }),
  b: Object.assign('two', { bar }),
};

/* The type of "foo" is:
{
  a: "one" & {
    bar: {
      prop1: number;
      prop2: number;
    };
  };
  b: "two" & {
    bar: {
      prop1: number;
      prop2: number;
    };
  };
}
*/

console.clear();

// This is a `String` (object), not a `string` (primitive):
console.log(foo.a); // String "one" { bar: { prop1: 1, prop2: 2 } }

// You can stringify it using any of these methods:
console.log(String(foo.a)); // "one"
console.log(foo.a.toString()); // "one"
console.log(`${foo.a}`); // "one"

console.log(foo.a.toUpperCase()); // "ONE"

console.log(foo.a.bar); // { prop1: 1, prop2: 2 }

console.log(foo.b); // String "two" { bar: { prop1: 1, prop2: 2 } }
console.log(String(foo.b)); // "two"
console.log(foo.b.toUpperCase()); // "TWO"
console.log(foo.b.bar); // { prop1: 1, prop2: 2 }
```

It would be better to devise a system for yourself of storing the value on a property on an object, (for example, as [David suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73070858/is-it-possible-to-have-optionally-nested-key-value-pairs-in-typescript/73072212#comment129056165_73070858), [using the `value` property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAZwOoEtgAsEFdgBqAhgDa7QC8UAShAMYJwAmAPMsHOgHYDmANFFxcA1lwQB3LgD4oAMigBvKADdS5APwAuKFwjKIcKAF8A3ACgzoSFGJkIAeQBGAK3rAWZqFAAqfT7EQUKAgAD2AILiZkAKQ0TBx8W3IoKloGZhZdfTgBLIMpPxkqJVU7bW9jORiUczMAMyE6YHQELigGAFtHbmgWX2ro0PDI6PhYjGw8QjUIKQAKf1Lycr8vMEDkbTGUPwBKbSSHFzc+gW3kGQV-OAhgXDg2hSWIAQA6d-XY0zMjCytoABCREMxX8nzAAEZtFxcF0DOY1oEAEzQ2GOeE-WoMLjsKCOYHaIEgxRQcFQqAQgTglFQJHGLGtXF1BAIFKKfxEbSdbq6OYAcghfIESnxhiMu1WeK5CC6PX5SKFJNFxglmIsAHoAFQ+LDQf5QBB1KAAImZCGNUHQmzMVy8nPZXi8z207E4vARjtF2ltjsRSHJMLhcA9vupqKDIfp-m+Xkc3v8TpmLo43B4ka9Dt9pMCAbRGKz2aQNMD6ODCajXm+v016os2OQCBIEFedCbwLmuwZOMbzZICB4czNryInag6vVJOdJohxoEGaUZO0lMLYBpdKMxjM9Z7rz7A6HRFez1H4+nxq3jJ3e8HLOHr1FJ4nC5zS6pyO067rl6bu-7N4Q96PpOSYmkis54gSJKLhSb5Fh+lS-NuP7XkOjhHjMQHGmBF7dshf6ofewJAc+-qviua6bmYp4ACIIKmUDYFaUA3MguAkMA0TcFARDtDKYDoE2hgGIgcBURO6J0EQuDINAnzKOgTD0eC0TiPE3Ems8FrggYoBiVA4h4CQTAGtk4icOEDG6ganA8NwpAqEmF6yryfINh00CuqmiokWAZFTnyuBYAaWB8iqJhjpq5YFtFMWxQAfglCVmN44DQK5Ka8KFTFiMA3HIMg6A8FwRCOE2DGsvqfJ5HAfKvHMSIAMxIkiuxQDWGoTgAgpEllEMArnqTwLLGYxvBmEAA)).

Comment: Thanks, good to know that it's an anti-pattern. I'll just use a `main` property or something to access the requested default value. Solution is cool to see, though.

Comment: Just beware that you probably want to also have a `children` property or something or else you can't have a child named `main`. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's a possible solution but it's maybe not exactly what you want.
See when creating an object (for ex. a class), you have to possibility to give it a `toString` method. This way when the object is concatenated into a string. It executes your method instead. Here's an example:

```js
const foo = {
  a: {
    prop1: 123,
    prop2: 456,
    toString(){
      return "1" }
    },
  b: {
    prop1: 123,
    prop2: 456,
    toString(){
      return "1"
    }
  }
}

// The problem is that if you want to get the `"1"` of an object. You have to convert it into a string like for example :

console.log(`${foo.a}`)
console.log(foo.a.toString())
console.log("" + foo.a)

// And of course you can still access every possible property

console.log(foo.a.prop1)
console.log(foo.b.prop2)
console.log(foo.b.prop1 + ' - ' + foo.b)
```